# 0000004a SSLHandshakeE E SSLC0008E: Unable to initialize SSL connection

Tags: eclipse, websphere-8

I am using Eclipse and have a Websphere in my local. I got the below error.

> 00000048 SSLHandshakeE E   SSLC0008E: Unable to initialize SSL
>   connection.  Unauthorized access was denied or security settings have
>   expired.  Exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL
>   message, plaintext connection?    at com.ibm.jsse2.b.a(b.java:33)     at
>   com.ibm.jsse2.nc.a(nc.java:456)   at
>   com.ibm.jsse2.nc.unwrap(nc.java:373)  at
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:26)     at
>   com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.readyInbound(SSLConnectionLink.java:534)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.ready(SSLConnectionLink.java:294)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)

My Eclipse is running on 64 bit.
I checked my Websphere 8.5.0.2 which is on 32 bit, will that cause any issue. I am using Windows 10.

Please let me know how to fix this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That often means plaintext is being sent to a secure port.